# relationship between container class and iterator class (in class diagram)

Tags: design-patterns, iterator, containers, uml, class-diagram

What is the relationship between the container class and the iterator class on the class diagram? In order to function properly, the container class has to have an iterator, so it is Dependency or just Assosiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A container class has a usage dependency to the iterator, since the container `«Create»` the iterator.

Conversely, an iterator needs to be associated with the container, to be able to iterate over it and find the accessed elements.

You can see [here on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) how it works.